# Solve Recursive Function

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I have this recursive equation and I need to write a solution for $E_x$ in terms of $x$ and $n$.
I have tried expanding it for some iterations to see if I could simplify it, but the terms don't simplify. The solutions for non-homogenous recurrence relations don't apply to this either, because of the $E_{\frac{x}{2}}$ term. Is there a math genius who can help me with this?

$
E_x = (1-\frac{x}{n}) (E_{x-1} + 1) + \frac{x}{n} (E_{\frac{x}{2}}+1)  
$

$
E_1=1
$

Comment: What would $E_{x/2}$ mean if $x$ were odd?

Comment: With these kinds of problems, $x/2$ is typically taken to be the floor of $x/2$ when $x$ is odd @RyanGreyling

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Thanks for the clarification, that's correct. The answer to this question would basically mean the average number of hops in the network for a request to get through from node with index x to node at index 1.

Comment: Any ideas on bounds also would be very helpful. I know it's somewhere between linear and logarithmic, but it's hard to figure.

Comment: Prehaps this rewritten form allows for more intuition: $E_x=E_{x-1}+1+\frac xn(E_{x/2}-E_{x-1})$

Comment: Would have been much good if you could have given the values for the first few digits, so as to find a pattern

Comment: @fishfag You mean from the bottom up?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I didn't saw that $n$, my bad

Comment: I can't believe for one second the equivalence that you claim. And what's the meaning of $E_{1-x/n+x^2/n^2}$ ?

Comment: @hadi: are you kidding ? What is $E_{0.77777\cdots}$ ?

Comment: my mistake, will fix

Comment: @YvesDaoust I was mistaken that I was mistaken xd, they're equivalent, there are some minor discrepancies because of the floating point computations. Index to  $E$ should round to the floor when not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

That $E_{\frac{x}{2}}$ is the hard part here, I got that for

$E_x = (1-\frac{x}{n}) (E_{x-1} + 1) + \frac{x}{n}+1$
$$E_x=\prod_{k=2}^{x}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)+\sum^{x-1}_{l=2}\left(\left(1+\frac{l}{n}\right)\prod_{m=l+1}^{x}\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)+\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)$$
And if you still want to fit that $E_{\frac{x}{2}}$;

$$E_x=\prod_{k=2}^{x}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)+\sum^{x-1}_{l=2}\left(\left(1+\frac{lE_{l/2}}{n}\right)\prod_{m=l+1}^{x}\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)+\sum_{p=1
}^{z-1}\left(\frac{1}{2^{T(p)}}\left(f\left(\frac{x}{2^p}\right)+1\right)\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^p\right)+\frac{1}{2^{T(z)}}\left(\frac{x}{n}\right)^z+0^{z-1}$$

Where $z=\lfloor\log_2x\rfloor$ and $T(x)$ is the $x$th triangular number,  but here:

$$T(x)=\frac{x(x-1)}{2}$$

And $$f(x)=\prod_{k=2}^{x}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)+\sum^{x-1}_{l=2}\left(\left(1+\frac{lE_{l/2}}{n}\right)\prod_{m=l+1}^{x}\left(1-\frac{m}{n}\right)\right)$$

All I'm saying is that even if we try to do some simplification we get an ugly monster like this, which is not even an exact formula! There is just an another extention of the recursive formula. Its like the same case of partitions, something where we can come up with recursive relations but a closed form will not be possible using existing mathematical operators.

Comment: The $E_{x/2}$ term is actually important, especially at first. I think a closed form wouldn't be possible for it. Putting some bound on it and a proof for it would be good too. So can assume some terms are worse to simplify it.

Comment: Added my bit in the  post.  Ill also have to do something on the bounds. Which I dont know if i could

Comment: How did you come up with that monstrosity :)  yea probably something easier than that, the complexity analysis is the main concern here (Big O). Also I tried upvoting your answer but website doesn't allow apparently because I'm new

Comment: I'm a super-virgin, that's why

Comment: haha ----------

Comment: Any luck on proving on kind of bounds for this?

Comment: I don't think I can, maybe putting a bounty on the question will be a good way to get attention, if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the effort dude

Comment: And also I believe you also got that for $n\rightarrow \infty$, $E_x=x$

Comment: That makes sense, practically too. This one is equivalent to the recursive function I have documented here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3397281/solve-tricky-recurrence-relation?noredirect=1#comment6989077_3397281

Comment: Question not found

Comment: And also the fact that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}E_x=x$$ can be proven by a method. I've also got that $$E_x=x+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=3}^{x}k(E_{k/2}-E_{k-1})$$ And also modifying it a little bit we can also get $$\lim_{x\to\infty}E_x=x+\frac{3}{n}(3+3E_3+4E_4+5E_5...)$$

Comment: The one I've posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3402476/help-solve-tricky-recurrence-relation   is interestingly equivalent to the one here but it's simpler. They're both different representations of our problem and give equal results computationally.

Comment: You got some answers there, is it any help? I do think exact formula's for such relations can only be achieved using nested summations, which is ugly.

Comment: No unfortunately, don't think that helps :/

Comment: $x$ is always less than $n$ so I guess the third one above is redundant.

Comment: Yeah, i know if $x\rightarrow \infty$, the answer's obvious infinity, but I just wanted to show that pattern.