# Help Solve Tricky Recurrence Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, recursion, recursive-algorithms

I have the following, and need to write it in terms of x, and n or provide a bound on its complexity (Big O), any ideas? (n is a constant, $1≤x<n$)

$
E(x)=1+E(x-1+\frac{x}{n}-\frac{x^2}{2n})\\
E(x\leq2)=1
$

Answer (score 0):

**This is not strictly speaking an answer to your question** but a step forward in the understanding of the goal.

I have programmed the recursive functional relationship : the recursive calls all end up in a finite number of steps (a major step that you will have to establish, common to all recursive definitions) and one obtains the following figure :

[image]

which looks to be very close to a function with equation :

$$y=\lceil a(1-e^{-bx}) \rceil$$

for some constants $a$ and $b$ where $\lceil A \rceil$ is the smallest integer at least equal to $A$.

Here is the Matlab program that has generated this figure :

> ```
>    function Erecur;
>    n=400;S=[];
>    for x=1:0.01:n;
>       S=[S,E(x)];
>    end;
>    plot(1:0.01:m,S,'r');
>    %%%
>    function y=E(x)
>    n=400;
>    if x<2
>       y=2;
>    else
>       y=1+E(x-1+x/n-(x.^2)/n);
>    end;
> ```

Comment: Yea I know that all calls would have a finite number of steps. This equation is basically the expected value of hops in the network where in each step, it could go half the way towards the target, or just one step depending on getting lucky or not.

Comment: But is there a rationale for getting a step function ?

Comment: to be honest I'm not sure how this helps, generally this is of interest for large numbers like x=15k and n=23k. I see you have put n=6 there, so it could be like that for small numbers, but I'm interested in its complexity and closed form (which I think is not possible)

Comment: Indeed, changing $n=6$ into $n=400$ gives a completely different figure (that I have included into my text). An example of a case where one can be fooled by a particular case. The rising branch look to be approximately of the form $y=$ integer part of $a(1-e^{bx})$ for some constants $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Hmm yea interesting, in your function y=E(x) it should be $\frac{(x^2)}{2n}$

Comment: Also, why is the value of $E(x)$ dropping again, that doesn't seem right to me

Comment: Corrected now... Sorry for this error.

Comment: no worries, thanks for that. Let me know if have any idea on how to put a bound on it, because I don't have a clue

Comment: In your equation, where do you think $n$ would fit

Comment: $2.1\sqrt{n}(1-exp(-x/(2.7\sqrt{n}))$ isn't a too bad fit (on the base of experiments till $n=2000$).

Comment: Hmm can it be proved mathematically?